# authentication during writing back passkeys on new devices

Tags: android

[diagram for android passkey sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMrdw.png)

As shown in the diagram,   I have 3  android phones  (Samsung, pixel and LG)
Before creating any passkeys,  Samsung and  pixel are configured with  same Google-password-manager  account and both phones have their own screen-locks.

Now I am creating first passkey in  BestBuy.com domain from  Samsung device.  The passkey nicely synched in Google-password-manager.
**I want to know that when Pixel device  writes back this passkey,  do I have to input my  screen-lock PIN of Samsung device ?**

And finally I bring up the third device i.e. LG and attach it to the same Google-password-manager  account.
**When this device starts synching passkeys from Google-password-manager ,  do I have to feed screen-lock PIN of Samsung or Pixel device ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for development topics only. For Android questions from user perspective you should post your question on https://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The PIN code (can be also faceId or touchId) is related only to a certain device, the passkeys doesn’t share this info between devices, as much as I know.